# Finding connection

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I want to find out if there are any circular connections using Python.
Let's say I have a matrix A:

```py
A = [["a", "b", "ab"], ["b", "d", "bd"], ["d", "c", "dc"], ["d", "a", "da"], ....]
```

In case of circular connection it prints the matrix T.
in this case:

```py
T = [["a", "b", "ab", "b", "d", "bd", "d", "a", "da"],...]`
```

I tried for loop inside for loop but I get weird results.

```py
M = [["a", "b", "ab"], ["b","d","bd"], ["c","d","cd"], ["d", "a", "da"]]
X = []
T = []

for i in M:
    if X != 0:
        X = i
        for j in M:
            if j[0] ==X[0] or j[0] == X[1] or j[1] == X[0] or j[1] == X[1]:
                T.append(j)
print(T)
```

Can anyone please help here? I am just a beginner at Python and would really apreciate any help.

Comment: The 1st thing that comes to mind would be to search for a cycle in a graph (your lists being the edges and individual letters the vertices): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Output_of_a_depth-first_search

Comment: have a look to [graphlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html). It raises an exception if a cycle is met

Comment: You could compute the [connected components](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components). As noted there, it will find "strong" connections which are bidirectional. A bidirectional path in a directed graph indicates a circle, right?